# Plone- Why am I getting a WrongContainedType error?

Tags: python, plone

I have an interface called IReportSettings for a registry key that has a tuple, which stores PersistantObjects that use an interface IUserSetting, which is implemented by an object type called UserSetting.  A factory adaptor for IUserSetting and UserSetting is registered with registerFactoryAdapter.
When I try to set the registry key's IReportSettings with a  tuple of UserSettings, I get an error:

```
WrongContainedType: ([WrongContainedType([WrongType('uname', <type 'unicode'>,'user_name')],'')],'value')
```

Here is some of my code:

```
class PersistentObject(PersistentField, schema.Object):
    pass

class IUserSetting(Interface):
    user_name = schema.TextLine(title=u"User",
                                required=True,
                                default=u"",
                   )

    field_a= schema.List(title=u"Field A",
                      value_type=schema.Choice(vocabulary=u'my.product.vocabularies.SomeVocabulary'),
                      required=False,
                      default=None
           )

    field_b = schema.TextLine(title=u"Field B",
                              required=False,
                              default = u"",
              )
    .
    .

class UserSetting(object):
    implements(IUserSetting)

    def __init__(self, user_name=u'', field_a=None, field_b=u'', ..):
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.field_a = field_a
        if field_a=None:
            self.field_a = []
        self.field_b = field_b
        ..

registerFactoryAdapter(IUserSetting, UserSetting)

class IReportSettings
    settings = schema.Tuple(
        title=u"User settings for a Report",
        value_type=PersistentObject(
                IUserSetting,
                title=u"User Setting",
                description=u"a Report Setting"
            ),
        required=False,
        default=(),
        missing_value=(),
    )
```

In a form class:

```
def saveUI(self, data):
    user_name = api.user.get_current().id
    field_a = data['field_a']
    field_b = data['field_b']
    .
    .
    registry_util = queryUtility(IRegistry)
    user_settings = registry_util.forInterface(IReportSettings,check=False)
    already_exists = False
    #Iterate through user_settings.settings and check if a setting for the user already exists, update if it exists or add new if it doesn't exist

    if already_exists == False:
        #Add new UserSetting - Example Data
        new_setting = UserSetting(user_name=user_name, field_a= field_a, field_b=field_b)
        user_settings.settings += (new_setting,)
```

new_setting is the correct type from when I printed it.  What data am I passing in could possibly be wrong?

In my registry.xml file, I added:

```
<records interface="my.package.user_settings.IReportSettings" purge="False"/>
```

Also, My code is based on this article:
http://blog.redturtle.it/plone.app.registry-how-to-use-it-and-love-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the article but I think that your problem is not realted to it.

Data stored inside your `user_name` must be a unicode but calling `api.user.get_current().id` will (probably) returns a 8bit string.

So try to change the line to:

```
user_name = api.user.get_current().id.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works.  I was confused by the error because I thought it was giving me a Unicode string.  I'll be sure to check for encoding when pulling information from api like that.
Also, that was a really good article you wrote.  It helped give me a better understanding of working with plone registry.